# Is it possible to avoid pressing Enter in the CMD?

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I don't have enough programming knowledge to discuss in detail, but I will try to describe the matter as best I can.

I have a small game using the CMD as a graphical environment. The character moves through a matrix using WASD. The movement works. The player has to enter a particular key (WASD) and then press ENTER for the character to move 1 unit between each square in the matrix.

The thing is, I would like to avoid having to press ENTER every time the move needs to be executed. As I understand it, the CMD has certain limitations in this regard. Should I resort to some third party library to achieve this?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: not sure if thats possible, but perhaps im wrong. as far as i know, the program cant read the input in the cmd unless you submit it (pressing ENTER). 
als0 here is the docs for JLine https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.jline/jline/latest/index.html

Comment: It looks like JLine is for line-based input, and won’t be of any help to you.  There might be third-party libraries for reading “raw” console input, but at this point, you’re probably better off [learning GUI development](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: You wrote a console-based game in pure Java? Or does your game use JNI (or JNA) or some third-party library?

Comment: @VGR I am doing a project and it is specifically requested to use the CMD as a graphical environment, so I cannot resort to a GUI.

Comment: @Abra I'm not sure, if I'm honest. I type in NetBeans, and as far as I remember, I installed something called "JSE" and I think also one called "JDK". I have three libraries in the project: java.util.Scanner, java.io.IOException, and java.util.Random.

Comment: google for "snake.bat" (written by dbenham). Extract the lines for reading keys. Also inspect the rest of the script - I think there is more knowledge that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

CMD was not build for that. And you need a workaround.

**Solution**

1. Create a KeyListener which listens on your KeysReleased Events.
2. After you release the key "W" for example, you can execute a key press and released by the application itself for the ENTER key.
3. You can not use the AWT/Swing `KeyListener` class for this. You need to write your own KeyListener.
4. Use the class `Robot` for pressing keys by application.

So if you have your CMD open and type AWSD, your OS will write the types Keys into your CMD and the KeyListener will press ENTER for you.

**Note**

You could try this as KeyListener:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = "";

   while (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") == false) {
       line = in.readLine();

       //do something
   }

   in.close();
```

Maybe you need a seconds `Thread`.

Comment: would that work for a command line application?

Comment: Yes. CMD = CoMmanD (prompt) :) The class Robot does not care about having a Window as UI.

Comment: When you use class [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html) it launches the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) which never terminates - unless you call `System.exit()`